# How to use IMemoryCache in a application with multiple instances

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, cloud-foundry

I'm using IMemoryCache in my ASP.Net core web application hosted by a cloud foundry.

The application has 3 instances.

Everything works fine, but when I want to remove the cache, it removes the cache logically only on one instance and the other two instances have still the old (cached) value.

My code looks like:

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       // other code...
       services.AddMemoryCache();
       // other code...
    }
```

ExampleController.cs

```
    private IMemoryCache cache;

    public ExampleController(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    private void ClearCacheByKey(string key)
    {
        this.cache.Remove(key);
    }
```

How can I handle the problem with the cache and multiple instances of my application?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @CodeCaster my application dosen't have a database

Comment: Then you missed the point of that link. Memory cache doesn't scale to multiple servers. You need a distributed cache. _One_ such a solution uses SQL Server, but you can also use Redis, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Memory cache uses the memory of your application to cache things. 
So you have three instances of memory cache, one on each instance of your application. Each one of them is independent of the others. If you write to one it won't write to the other instances, and the same is valid for deleting.

That being said, it would be better I think if you use a centralized caching mechanism. So that all the instances of your application call the same cache instance.

Alternatively, but **I wouldn't recommend doing this**, you can create an endpoint to clear the cache that you need to invoke when invalidating the cache on a machine, to invalidate it on all the other instances of the application.

Comment: If you still want to use IMemoryCache. You can have an application that does just that, and all the others use that for getting/deleting data from the cache.

Comment: Side Note: If your app is running on Cloud Foundry, when you send requests they will be round robin'd across all your app instances. For cases like clearing in-memory cache, where you need to ensure a request makes it to each app instance, you can use the `X-CF-APP-INSTANCE` header for force a request to a particular instance, see https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/http-routing.html#app-instance-routing. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar requirements and implemented it as below. I hope it gives you an idea.

I created a proxy class as below:

```
public class MemoryCacheProxy : IMemoryCache
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private readonly string _name;

    public MemoryCacheProxy(string name)
    {
        _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
        _name = name;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cache.Dispose();
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(object key, out object value)
    {
        return _cache.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICacheEntry CreateEntry(object key)
    {
        return _cache.CreateEntry(key);
    }

    public void Remove(object key)
    {
        _cache.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

Then I created a CacheManager:

```
public class CacheManager : ICacheManager
{
    private readonly MemoryCacheProxy _appCache;
    private readonly MemoryCacheProxy _userCache;

    public CacheManager()
    {
        _appCache = new MemoryCacheProxy("ApplicationCache");
        _userCache = new MemoryCacheProxy("UserCache");
    }

    public void Set(string key, object value, CacheScope scope)
    {
        var cache = scope == CacheScope.Application ? _appCache : _userCache;
        cache.Set(key, value, DateTimeOffset.MaxValue);
    }

    public T? Get<T>(string key, CacheScope scope) where T : class
    {
        var cache = scope == CacheScope.Application ? _appCache : _userCache;
        object result;
        if (cache.TryGetValue(key, out result))
        {
            return (T)result;
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    public T? Pop<T>(string key, CacheScope scope) where T : class
    {
        var result = Get<T>(key, scope);
        if (result != null)
        {
            Remove(key, scope);
            return result;
        }
        return default;
    }

    public void Remove(string key, CacheScope scope)
    {
        var cache = scope == CacheScope.Application ? _appCache : _userCache;
        cache.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

Other required definitions:

```
public enum CacheScope
{
    User,
    Application
}

public interface ICacheManager
{
    public void Set(string key, object value, CacheScope scope);
    public T? Get<T>(string key, CacheScope scope) where T : class;
    public T? Pop<T>(string key, CacheScope scope) where T : class;
    public void Remove(string key, CacheScope scope);
}
```